# How does the web container manage the lifecycle of a spring controller

Tags: spring-mvc

If i write a simple servlet application, in my servlet class i extend the http servlet. This lets the container know that my class is a servlet and it will manage the 'lifecycle' of the servlet. init, doget(), destroy() etc.

But the Spring MVC framweork controller class does not extend any servlet class. it is jsut a POJO with it s own custom methods. Now I can call those methods individually using Requestmapping.

But will this spring controller class be 'mananged' by the container in a same way a servlet lifecyle is managed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But will this spring controller class be 'mananged' by the container
>   in a same way a servlet lifecyle is managed?

Not directly. Then entry point of a Spring MVC application is typically a [`DispatcherServlet`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/DispatcherServlet.html)*. This class extends (not directly, but through inheritance) `HttpServlet`. You declare it as you would any other `Servlet`, typically in `web.xml`.

However you don't declare it by itself. You provide a Spring `ApplicationContext` from which the `DispatcherServlet` can go and get the `@Controller` annotated classes it will use to handle requests.

The `DispatcherServlet` handler stack is pretty big. There are many components involved. [The official Spring MVC is an excellent document.](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html) You should read it.

*I say typically because Spring provides other handlers, `HttpRequestHandler` for example.

---

Additional Reading:

1. [Spring MVC and Servlets 3.0 - Do you still need web.xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15008126/spring-mvc-3-2-and-servlets-3-0-do-you-still-need-web-xml)
2. [What happens behind the scenes of deploying a Spring MVC application to tomcat outside of eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19140943/what-happens-behind-the-scenes-of-deploying-a-spring-mvc-application-to-tomcat-o/19141051#19141051)
3. [What's the difference between @Component, @Repository & @Service annotations in Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6827752/whats-the-difference-between-component-repository-service-annotations-in)
4. [Spring MVC: difference between <context:component-scan> and <annotation-driven /> tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13661985/spring-mvc-difference-between-contextcomponent-scan-and-annotation-driven)
5. [Difference between <context:annotation-config> vs <context:component-scan>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7414794/difference-between-contextannotation-config-vs-contextcomponent-scan?lq=1)
6. [ContextLoadListener and DispatcherServlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3234544/contextloadlistener-and-dispatcherservlet)

Comment: Thanks. But the individual controllers still follow a lifecycle?

Comment: @KaushikGuha The controllers are spring managed beans. Their lifecycle is tied to that of the `ApplicationContext` to which they belong. That is usually tied to the lifecyle of the `DispatcherServlet` which depends on the container.

Comment: in a traditional servlet i can write initialisation code and cleanup code in the init() and destroy() method. In a spring managed bean, is there a way to do it? Thank you

Comment: @KaushikGuha Yes, if you go in the chapter 5 of the Spring documentation, you can declare `init` and `destroy` type methods for your bean classes. When the `ApplicationContext` is closed or destroyed, the `destroy` method will get called for any bean declaring it. The `init` method (not necessarily by that name, but there are rules) will be called with the bean is created.